# What is the time complexity of this recursive solution for removing duplicates?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, duplicates

After I complete a Leetcode question, I always try to also determine the asymptotic time complexity, for practice.

I am now looking at problem [26. Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/):

> Given a sorted array *nums*, remove the duplicates in-place such that
> each element appears only once and returns the new length.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by
> **modifying the input array *in-place*** with O(1) extra memory.
>
> #### Clarification:
>
> Confused why the returned value is an integer but your answer is an
> array?
>
> Note that the input array is passed in by **reference**, which means a
> modification to the input array will be known to the caller as well.
>
> Internally you can think of this:
>
> ```
> // nums is passed in by reference. (i.e., without making a copy) int
> len = removeDuplicates(nums);
>
> // any modification to nums in your function would be known by the caller. 
> // using the length returned by your function, it prints the first len elements.
> for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
>     print(nums[i]);
> }
> ```
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> **Input:** `nums = [1,1,2]`
> **Output:** `2, nums = [1,2]`
> **Explanation:** Your
> function should return length = 2, with the first two elements of *nums*
> being 1 and 2 respectively. It doesn't matter what you leave beyond
> the returned length.

My code:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number}
 */
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    nums.forEach((num,i) => {
       if(nums[i+1] !== null && nums[i+1] == nums[i] ){
           nums.splice(i, 1);
           console.log(nums)
           removeDuplicates(nums)
       }
    })
    return nums.length;
};
```

For this problem, I got *O(log n)* from my research. Execution time halves each time it runs. Can someone please verify or determine if I am wrong?

Are all recursive functions inherently *O(logn)*? Even if there are multiple loops?

Comment: Are you expecting literal `null` in your array?

Comment: yes as if the next value is non existent

Comment: Why is this recursive? I don't see the advantage here.

Comment: Don't test that way, test `i + 1 < nums.length` or `typeof(nums[i+1]) != 'undefined'`.

Comment: How would you have solved it? it was my first hypothesis and cleanest way to do it

Comment: This could be O(n), however your solution is worse as it rechecks all elements on the recursive call.

Comment: If you're using recursion you normally do it on a subset of the thing you're working with, like many sorting routines do. Here you just pass the whole thing in for some reason. That suggests this is really a loop of some kind.

Comment: It depends on the constraints. Can you re-order the elements? Can you lean on things like [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)?

Comment: Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory

Comment: 0 <= nums.length <= 3 * 104
-104 <= nums[i] <= 104
nums is sorted in ascending order.  https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/

Comment: "*Are all recursive functions inherently O(long)? even if there are multiple loops*" (assuming you mean `log n`) - not. It's not possible for all recursive functions to have this performance characteristic. `len = (list, count = 0) => list.length === 0 ? count : len(count.slice(1), count + 1)` will be only `O(n)` and cannot be anything else. *Some* recursive functions will be `O(log n)` like tree traversal or binary searches. However, some will have higher complexity like finding all permutations or fibonacci numbers.

Comment: "*Do not allocate extra space for another array*" you can always pass around indexes to bisect your data, rather than actually getting a new subset. You get the same result in the end, it's just how you represent your subsets.

Comment: Can you please explain  or point to``` reference  pass around indexes to bisect your data, rather than actually getting a new subset.```

Comment: Also yes my computer has auttocorrect/grammarly

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Comment: If you accept, say, `data` as an array and a `pivot` which is an index to check before and after, then you've effectively gotten half of your array. It might be even easier to get a `from` and `to` parameters that specify start and end index that you're interested in. Do one check, narrow down the search space by half, recursively call with the same `data` but `from` and `to` that have half the range than before. Make a new check, halve the search space, repeat until done. Classic binary search algorithm.

Comment: I _think_ your alorithm is O(n²) worst case and O(n) best case, average case somewhere inbetween. (to actually answer your question)

Comment: "I got O(log n) from my research execution time halves for each time its run. " How did you do this test? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For this problem, I got *O(log n)* from my research. Execution time halves for each time it's run. Can someone please verify or determine if I am wrong?

The execution time does not halve for each run: imagine an extreme case where the input has 100 values and they are all the same. Then at each level of the recursion tree *one* of those duplicates will be found and removed. Then a deeper recursive call is made. So for every duplicate value there is a level in the recursion tree. So in this extreme case, the recursion tree will have a depth of 99.

Even if you would revise the algorithm, it would not be possible to make it *O(log n)*, as all values in the array need to be read at least once, and that alone already gives it a time complexity of *O(n)*.

Your implementation uses `splice` which needs to shift all the values that follow the deletion point, so one `splice` is already *O(n)*, making your algorithm *O(n²)* (worst case).

Because of the recursion, it also uses *O(n)* extra space in the worst case (for the call stack).

> Are all recursive functions inherently *O(logn)*?

No. Using recursion does not say anything about the overall time complexity. It could be anything. You typically get *O(logn)* when you can ignore *O(n)* (like half) of the current array when making the recursive call. This is for instance the case with a Binary Search algorithm.

### Improvement

You can avoid the extra space by not using recursion, but an iterative method. Also, you are not required to actually *change* the length of the given array, only to *return* what its new length should be. So you can avoid using `splice`. Instead, use two indexes in the array: one that runs to the next character that is different, and another, a slower one, to which you copy that new character. When the faster index reaches the end of the input, the slower one indicates the size of the part that has the unique values.

Here is how that looks:

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    if (nums.length == 0) return 0;
    let len = 1;
    for (let j = 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        if (nums[j-1] !== nums[j]) nums[len++] = nums[j];
    }
    return len;
};
```

Comment: If you don't want to modify the array, you should write `len++` though instead of `nums[len++] = nums[j];`. If you *do* want to in-place filter the array, you will need to also drop the remaining elements at the end by `nums.length = len;` after the loop.

Comment: The OP should add the specification of the Leetcode question, which I believe is [this one](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/). It requires an in-place modification, and to return the new length without the need to shorten the input array. This solution passes the tests at Leetcode.

Comment: "*It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the returned length.*" - oh, wow, that is so weird. However, the example outputs *do* shorten the array, and there doesn't appear to be a requirement that precludes doing it.

Comment: Indeed, it is weird. As Leetcode measures execution time and gives you a comparative score, there is a habit at Leetcode to exclude anything that is not required, like here: adapting the array's length.

Comment: @Tyrique, did this answer your question?

Comment: Hey Trincot Thank you as usual you came with an in-depth answer

Comment: Hi trincot  could you explain this line? ` if (nums[j-1] !== nums[j]) nums[len++] = nums[j];`

Comment: It adds 1 to len if the values do not match correct  but why nums[len++]? and why is it = nums[j]?